# How to have different heights of geoJson polygons?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am plotting the geojson file of all the polygons in a map using the leaflet library as below:

```
  geojson = L.geoJson(geoJOSNFile, {
                     style: style,
                     onEachFeature: onEachFeature
                }).addTo(map);
```

this gives something like

```
http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/
```

Now I want to show the polygon in different height instead of color by their properties.
Is this can be done in leaflet.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "different height"?

Comment: I am actually looking for Something like this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90061/3d-perspective-on-maps-in-leaflet-cartodb.   But I couldn't find anythingg so Itried to plot 10 layers for one geojson district and others 1 layer.But that did not show any difference.